# Control name got changed after uploading

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, .net

I'm developing an asp.net web application.
And having an radio button list on my web form `ID="rblOpt"`.
I'm publish that application on my local IIS.

When i call that application from browser and see the source code by View page source.
Then it shows radio button list's ID.

```
ID="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_rblOpt"
```

When i upload this folder to my dedicated hosting account then it shows

```
ID="ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_rblOpt"
```

And so on with my other controls.

Can any one tell me why there is difference between control names.

Comment: I am not sure about the reason, but if it is causing problem for you then use `Control.ClientID` for accessing it through JavaScript/jQuery or specify `ClientIDMode=Static`, if you are using .Net 4.0 or higher

Comment: @AshishRathore Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work since it seems you have not yet discovered how to accept answers.

Answer (score 1):

If your Framework version is `4.0` or higher then put `ClientIDMode="Static`". you'll get your desired id at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code if you are Using .Net 4.0

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="PO" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```